# Listview value to combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have this combobox fetching values from SQL:

```
public void brandSelectCB(ComboBox cb)
{
    string sSQL = " SELECT" +
                  "      id, name" +
                  "  FROM" +
                  "      tbBrand" +
                  "  ORDER BY" +
                  "      name";

    sqlConnect connect = new sqlConnect();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = connect.getBD(sSQL);

    cb.DataSource = dt;
    cb.DisplayMember = "name";
    cb.ValueMember = "id";
}
```

I have also a listview like this:

```
public void modelSelect(ListView lvModel)
{
    string sSQL = " SELECT" +
                  "      tbModel.id, tbBrand.name AS brand, tbModel.name" +
                  "  FROM" +
                  "      tbBrand, tbModel" +
                  " WHERE" +
                  "     tbBrand.id = tbModel.brand" +
                  " ORDER BY" +
                  "     tbBrand.name, tbModel.name";

    sqlConnect connect = new sqlConnect();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = connect.getBD(sSQL);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["id"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["brand"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["name"].ToString());

        lvModel.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

When I select a row from the listview and click the edit button, it should get the values from that selected row to the corresponding comboboxes and textboxes:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.txtID.Text = lvModels.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
    this.cbBrand.SelectedText = lvModels.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
    this.txtName.Text = lvModels.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
}
```

but I get no values on the comboboxes, only in the textboxes. I realize that it is because the combo is in dropdownlist style, and i should use `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` but neither of them seems to work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
string brandText = lvModels.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
DataRow itemToSelect = ((DataTable) this.cbBrand.DataSource)
                          .Rows
                          .Cast<DataRow>()
                          .FirstOrDefault(r=>r.Field<string>("name").Equals(brandText));
if(itemToSelect != null)
   cbBrand.SelectedItem = itemToSelect;
```

Disclaimer:  I didn't test this out; this is from memory.

This would be simpler if you stashed the BrandID somewhere in the `ListViewItem`: then you could use `SelectedValue`.

Comment: i got it working like this you gave me an idea... your answer was too complicated for me :) thanks anyway

int xcb;
xcb = this.cbBrand.FindString(lvMain.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text);
this.cbBrand.SelectedIndex = xcb;